# Unable to set a value to a variable

Tags: java, android, firebase, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pass a variable  from a method to another without using parameter .I have declared the value globally but still the value returned is null when the value is called in second method

```
    String profileName;//globally declared
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("Logger", "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                       profileName=user.optString("name"); 
`//assigns the correct value here*`*


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),profileName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
    private void updateUI() {


         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You Logged Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Facebook.this,Add.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("ProfileName",profileName );
    //profileName is set to null though i am assigning the value in the method onCompleted**
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
```

Comment: The method `executeAsync();` should tell you why (hint: read the name).

Comment: Tangential to your question, but remember that Java doesn't actually support global variables. Declaring a variable as static would allow it to be referenced anywhere, but is a terrible practice. It is more common for any variable you want at a global scope to be declared final inside of an interface. Your string "profileName" is currently Package Private.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart should I return some value within in executeAsync

Comment: @Shelldboy execute**Async**

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart I am new to programming I know i should execute  butasynchronously but how